# AKSequencer timebase - Host Time

Tags: ios, audiokit

Anyway to get the timebase from AKSequencer when it's playing ?

Timebase is needed to sync properly with some functions and other apps. I tried with this function, but each beat timebase is decreasing.

```
func getTimebase() -> UInt64 {
    if sequencer.isPlaying {
        let posSeconds = sequencer.currentPosition.seconds
        let timeBase = mach_absolute_time() - AVAudioTime.hostTime(forSeconds: posSeconds)
        return timeBase
    } else { return 0 }
}
```

Printing timeBase: print("timeBase: ",timeBase)

```
timeBase:  24584445928131
timeBase:  24584430726122
timeBase:  24584421019729
timeBase:  24584408406139
timeBase:  24584397028323
timeBase:  24584384435312
```

Comment: What have you tried? Give us some context, code, or ideally a sample project.

Comment: Question updated. I think AKSequencer needs a function to get the Beat 0 Host Time

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you need here? If you just need hostTime at beat 0, couldn't you use an AKCallbackInstrument to check it? It isn't quite what you mean by 'timebase' here.

Comment: No. What I need it the Host Time at first beat when AK Sequencer is playing. Host Time when the sequence started

Comment: I wrote a similar function to yours: let elapsedTime = mach_absolute_time() - AVAudioTime.hostTime(forSeconds: sequencer.currentPosition.seconds) . . . And the variation is (at most) about 0.1 ms on my hardware devices (a little higher on the simulator).  Not sure why your values are decreasing.  What are you running this on? and where are you calling your function from?